# Tableau, how to automate excel file with sql query to refresh every day?

Tags: excel, tableau-api

Just a general question here, but if I connect an excel file to Tableau that is really just a select * from a database table, will Tableau refresh the excel file or will it just stay as stale data?

If tableau will not trigger the query, Is there a way to automate the excel file relatively painlessly?

Comment: Why not just connect Tableau directly to the database and skip the Excel step?

Comment: If tableau is allowed to connect with excel, you have to give directions to excel about the refresh rate it has to apply with its connection with database

Comment: The problem is I am at the mercy of Sybase, and we are unable to establish a connection.  For excel refresh automation, is this done in vba or how exactly is that done?

Answer (score 0):

Depends where is your Excel file and if it's going to be published in a Tableau server. I would try and figure out why you can't establish a connection to Sybase. It could be that you're just missing the drivers for Tableau.

Have you checked https://help.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/examples_sybasease.htm